# Javascript library for upload image or get it from webcam and crop

Tags: javascript, image, upload, crop, webcam

I'm looking for a JS tool creating profile images.
I need to upload or get it from webcam. and crop it.
I already have a solution based on webcamjs but i would like to know if there is any integrated tool for uploading/capture and crop.